# What happens when I initialize an array having the size as a variable?

Tags: c++, dynamic, heap-memory, variable-length-array, stack-memory

I want to know where is my array stored if it has variable size such as in the code below this is because in my textbook it says that during runtime memory is allocated to the heap to my understanding, but it seems that it actually allocated to the stack can someone clarify how stack and heap memory allocation actually works.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
int Array_size;
cin >> Array_size;
int array[Array_size];
return 0;
}
```

Comment: That is not valid C++. it uses VLA extension.

Comment: this is not valid c++

Comment: That's not valid standard c++. The standard doesn't support variable length arrays. Just look that up.

Comment: You can't do that in a standard compliant manner in C++. Use a `std::vector`.

Comment: Answer: you invoke *Undefined Behavior* and a compiler error -- unless your compiler supports the VLA extension for C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your book is wrong, or you are misreading it.

A [**Variable-Length Array**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array#Variable-length_arrays) (a *non-standard extension* implemented by few C++ compilers) is always allocated in *automatic memory* (ie, on the stack), never in *dynamic memory* (ie, on the heap).  The array's memory is reclaimed by the compiler when the array goes out of scope, just like any other local variable.

Dynamic memory is allocated only by [the `new` operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new), or by the `[std::](m|c)alloc()` functions.

Answer (score 0):

Stack and heap memory are a bit abstract so I understand your confusion. In general, any variables inside functions, including main, that are not dynamically allocated (i.e. declaring a variable using new) go on the stack. If you declare a pointer, that pointer points to a variable on the heap while the pointer remains on the stack. This is why you must always clear the pointer using delete and, preferably, set the pointer to NULL if it has no more use. Any variables or functions that are pushed onto the stack are popped automatically (think of push and pop as inserting and removing, it’s just correct terminology). Memory on the heap is allocated and deallocated manually and during runtime. Hopefully that clears some confusion.